# Ошибка при внесении изменений в код C++

Tags: c++, qtcreator, build

[image: вот такая ошибка еще]

Есть код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
int main()
{
std::queue<std::string> myQueue;
myQueue.push("This is");
myQueue.push(" myQueue");
std::cout << myQueue.front()<<myQueue.back()<<std::endl;
std::cout << "There are "<<myQueue.size()<< " items in the myQueue"<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

При первом запуске и всех последующих он работает,но, если внести какие-либо изменения, например поставить пробел после `There are`, то при следующей сборке сыпет тысячи ошибок и на время сборки qtcreator виснет. Удаляю папку сборки и снова собираю решение и вуаля, все норм. Что происходит и как это исправить?
Ошибки:

- в первую очередь ругается на объявление queue и все дальнейшие упоминания myQueue(смотри код) `no member 'queue' in namespace 'std'`
- второе,

```
/home/user/qtp/queue/build-queue-Desktop_Qt_5_13_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/queue:1: ошибка: stray ‘\350’ in program
 libstdc++.so.6 __gmon_start__ _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable _ITM_registerTMCloneTable _ZStlsIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES7_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS4_S5_T1_EE _ZNSaIcED1Ev _ZNSolsEm _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_ _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EOS4_ _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E _ZSt17__throw_bad_allocv __cxa_begin_catch _ZdlPv __gxx_personality_v0 _ZNSaIcEC1Ev _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc _Znwm _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev __cxa_rethrow _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev _ZSt4cout __cxa_end_catch libgcc_s.so.1 _Unwind_Resume libc.so.6 __stack_chk_fail __cxa_atexit __cxa_finalize memmove __libc_start_main GCC_3.0 GLIBC_2.4 GLIBC_2.2.5
```

и еще тысячи таких однотипных ошибок.

Comment: Лечится, если запускать `g++` вместо `gcc`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe возможно, но g++ нет в списке компиляторов при настройке комплекта в qtcreator, хотя он установлен. Там только разные версии gcc

Comment: @AlexGlebe разобрался как добавить компилятор g++ но не помогло

Comment: Выложите весь `Makefile`, посмотрим.

Comment: Вручную вызовите `g++ /home/user/..путь../main.cpp`. Если всё ok, тогда ковыряться нужно в `qtcreator`. А если всё равно проблема, значит в `g++` не до установили что-то.

Comment: @AlexGlebe так я уж понял что с qtcreator проблема. Ибо сам по себе g++ все собирает без проблем